# Flutter dart : Url launcher Not throw error Page

Tags: flutter, dart

I purposely put the wrong url so I can see my error page, but it doesn't show anything

this my code

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://goo.gl/maps/HiKcRmtjE2if58aw7');
    final Uri _url = Uri.parse('adjja');

    final Uri _wa = Uri.parse('https://wa.me/62895378147657');

    
    
    Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
      if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
        throw Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorPage()));
      }
    }
```

Comment: throw is not meant to be uszd like this, you can directly call the `push()` when the `!await launchUrl(_url)` is true

Comment: throw keyword is used to create exceptions. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#throw

Comment: can you make the code? i'am still confuse

Answer (score 0):

remove throw and You can check if url is valid or not by using canLaunchUrl method

```
 if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
  await launchUrl(
    url,
    mode: _useWebView
        ? LaunchMode.inAppWebView
        : LaunchMode.externalApplication,
  );
} else {
  Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorPage()));
}
```

Comment: sorry, but _useWebView is not defined,i've try remove throw

Comment: That param is if you want to use the webview or not just dont consider that param and use this. @NioZihni

Comment: i see, still not shwing error page huft:)

Comment: what is the error